# How do I adjust display contrast and brightness in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, display

How can I adjust the contrast and brightness of a monitor in Ubuntu if the drivers are just for Windows?

Is there software that can do it without having to use the graphic drivers?

Comment: What about the contrast?

Comment: My Dell 13z laptop won't allow me to increase the brightness when in a Linux distro. Ubuntu is convinced that it's already at maximum brightness. I can however change it (using the Fn key combo) while BIOS is loading, so at least I don't need to boot into Windows to do it.

Answer (score 6):

It would really help to know what sort of laptop you have, which video card, which monitor and whether you are on Gnome/KDE.

If you are using Gnome, the [Gnome Color Manager](http://projects.gnome.org/gnome-color-manager/) could be a solution (not available with all gnome versions).

If you are using KDE with LCD, the luminosity applet [KLcdDimmer](http://klcddimmer.sourceforge.net/) might be a solution.

The gamma level may be adjustable with the xgamma command (not available with all video cards).

If you are using nvidia, you could edit ~/.nvidia-settings-rc, and call `nvidia-settings --load-config-only`.

For sony vaio the brightness and volume function keys may exist with installing [fsfn](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-2722251.html#2722251).

You can search for a better video driver for your card on [X.Org](http://www.x.org/). Some of them have a bundled utility to adjust gamma/contrast/brightness.

Answer (score 3):

Is it an LCD monitor? You can try this from the command line:

```
$sudo echo -n 100 > /proc/acpi/video/VGA/LCD/brightness
```

If it's too bright use a lower number. If you have GLX instead of VGA the file is `/proc/acpi/video/GLX0/LCD/brightness`.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=xx
```

Where `xx` is the desired brightness in hexadecimal ranging from `00` (brightest) to `FF` (no brightness at all).

Answer (score 1):

Just a few hours ago, I installed Quantal Quetzal Ubuntu, I just went to dash home and typed "settings" and selected the Power Settings, then clicked the "Brightness Settings" link and finally adjust the desired brightness.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround that might work for you in [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acpid/+bug/392948). This relies on adding `acpi_osi=Linux` to the kernel boot option. Others seems to have more success with these options: `nomodeset acpi_backlight=vendor`

These options can be passed via Grub. You might want to try them out by editing these commands in the Grub menu before putting it in Grub's configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu go to System > Preferences > Power management
there you find a brightness bar slider set it to the desired brightness level and to keep the change permanent check on the Make default check box