# Adjust output Brightness/Gamma/Colors in Gnome

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, xorg, brightness

We have a desktop system running Ubuntu 8.04.4, and it is connected to a standard desktop LCD monitor.  Unfortunately, in 8.04.4, the brightness of the image is cranked way up.  It appears to be a graphics driver issue.  Unfortunately, installing a newer GPU driver for this Intel GPU is very difficult to do.  So, I am looking for a software (or config file?) solution to achieve this.

Note: Ubuntu 9.10 and higher do not exhibit this issue, so this is not a hardware problem.
Note: VNC-ing to this machine from another does not exhibit this issue either.

Also, I installed "DisplayCalibrator.app", and it does not work very well (the app comes up, but the contents of the window are blank).

Is there anything that I can add to the xorg.conf file to correct this issue?

Also, this solution: [How do I adjust display contrast and brightness in Ubuntu?](https://superuser.com/questions/96539/adjust-contrast-and-brightness-in-ubuntu) did not resove my issue.

Comment: Why would you use 8.04.4? LTS is a good reason but 10.04 is also a LTS release. So why ? (Not like it would be a problem, Im just curious)

Comment: Our software development environment requires 8.04.  We are currently working on an upgrade path to 10.04, but that will take some time to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Gnome Color Manager](http://projects.gnome.org/gnome-color-manager/) seems to be a natural choice, but I haven't used it myself and am not sure if it can be integrated with your gnome version.

Comment: That app is **EXACTLY** what I'm looking for.

Unfortunately, it's not included on 8.04.  Is there an easy way of installing it?  I'm trying to find other ICC profile apps for 8.04.  I'll post them if I find them.

(If my reputation was 15, I would rank you up, but I'm only a 6)